# Angular 8 WebRTC Can't make it work on 2 tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, webrtc

I have a task to create an audio chat room between 2 users.

I used app example:
[Peer connection: audio only](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/)

I've changed the code to TypeScript, and it works:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmwaku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

But I can't make it work between two users (not in one tab; I open 2 firefox windows). I have only very basic knowledge of Angular. To be honest, I'm not an Angular developer and normally I write desktop apps, but I need to develop this app with Angular.

I need to send an offer event to a communication platform(to a room with another user - it's always 2 users in the room). It needs a type: `offer` and `sdp`.

Other user responds with an answer event to the same platform, to the same room. It also needs `sdp`, and type set to `answer`.

We use matrix.org.
Here's [VOIP specs](https://matrix.org/docs/spec/client_server/r0.6.1#voice-over-ip)

I have already implemented sending these events to a communication platform, I read events from the room, and if there's a call offer event, I can answer with an answer event, but I can't make it work.

I've tried to make it work, so I had to work on last weekend, but there's always some issue like `DOMException: "Cannot set remote answer in state stable"` etc.

Of course I don's ask for a working code(I know it's a work for few days), but I would appreciate any advice to help me implement it, make it easier and possible for someone with very basic knowledge of Angular and webRTC.

Oh, and I'm not sure why, but this stackblitz example doesn't work in Chrome for me, but it works in firefox.

//EDIT

I'm still trying to find a solution. I try to do something like this now:

```
placeCall() {
    this.turnServer();
    this.uuid = this.createUuid();
    this.initCall();
}

 initCall(){
    this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(PEER_CONNECTION_CONFIG);
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
      })
      .then(stream => this.gotStreamSetOffer(stream))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('error');
        alert(`getUserMedia() error: ${e.name}`);
      });
  }


 gotStreamSetOffer(stream) {
    this.hangupButton.nativeElement.disabled = false;
    this.localStream = stream;
    let audioTracks = this.localStream.getAudioTracks();
    console.log(audioTracks);
    if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Using Audio device: ${audioTracks[0].label}`);
    }
    
    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => this.pc1.addTrack(track, this.localStream));
    this.pc1.createOffer(this.offerOptions)
      .then(v => {
        this.pc1.setLocalDescription(v);
        this.sdp = v.sdp;
        this.localOfferSDP = v;
        this.messageService.callInvite(JSON.stringify(new CallInviteModel(this.uuid, 0, 30000, new OfferModel("offer", v.sdp))), this.roomId).subscribe(res => {
            this.candidates();
        });
      });
    this.pc1.onicecandidate = e => {
      if (e.candidate) return;
    };
       // Wait for answer in room and sanve answer to v

     this.hangupButton.nativeElement.disabled = false;
     this.callId = v.content.call_id;
     this.remoteOfferSDP = v.content.answer;
     this.pc1.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(this.remoteOfferSDP));

  }

 answer() {
    this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(PEER_CONNECTION_CONFIG);
    let answer = new AnswerModel("answer", this.localOfferSDP.sdp); // localOfferSDP is an offer object with fields type and sdp. It's assigned when call event is detected
    let callAnswer = new CallAnswerModel(this.callId, 0, answer);
    let json = JSON.stringify(callAnswer);
    this.messageService.callAnswer(json, this.roomId).subscribe(res => {

    });
    this.remoteOfferSDP = this.localOfferSDP;
    this.remoteOfferSDP.type = 'answer';
    this.pc1.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(this.localOfferSDP))
      .then((a) => this.pc1.createAnswer())
      .then(d => {
        this.pc1.setLocalDescription(this.remoteOfferSDP)
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    this.pc1.onicecandidate = e => {
      if (e.candidate) return;

      };  

  }
```

But now I again get an error: `DOMException: "Cannot set remote answer in state stable"`

//EDIT2
Now I get an exception: `DOMException: "Answer contains illegal setup attribute "actpass" at level 0"`. `actpass` is in `sdp` and it's generated automatically. I receive this error in FF.

Comment: My bad, I didn't set answer correctly. Now i receive `ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details`.  [Screen about:webrtc](https://imgur.com/6DNdI8W)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did this by doing these things:

1. Added `adapter.js`, so now it works in different browsers.
2. I added `ontrack` to make audio works
3. I create an offer, then set codecs and local description(I need to do this before I send an event to matrix room, to send candidates)
4. When there's no more candidates I send an offer event to matrix room.
5. When I see an offer event, I set remote description to the remote offer
6. I create an answer, set codecs, and then local description and I send an answer event to the room.
7. When there's answer event in the room i set remote description to that event

I know this list is not very helpful, but maybe it will help someone.